# Geometric Normal in Nodes Editor / Material Nodes for a different Object

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, normals

[image]
[image]

Is is possible to get the Geometric Normal/Rotation Orientation in Node Editor / Material Nodes of a different Object?

Cycles with a image sequence.

Above we see the Normal node in a  Node Editor window/ Materials Nodes.  It would be useful  to have  the orientation follow that of some [other] object.  Is there an efficient method for doing this?

In the nodes I am using a static normal as depicted as a inferior substitute for a dynamically moving normal. Currently the single normal would exist across all frames, which is failed.   A UV project modifier is used which projects on potentially all faces.  This is not what is needed so the texture is removed on certain faces.  The certain faces are determined with the static normal substitute.  The simplified static normal will not work acceptably in all cases.  The sphere depicted is a simple testing object, and not necessarily a final object.

I may consider compositing a threshold filtered gray level image.

[image]

- Image above is preferable since sphere has dark untextured backside.  This is the easy case.  Light Source and Static Normal are parallel/compatible.

[image]

- Image above is failed since sphere has textured backside.

[image]

- Image above is failed since sphere shadow and texture are not coincident.  The wall shadow is desired as is.  The light source and static normal are not compatible/parallel.

[image]

- Image above is acceptable since sphere shadow and texture are coincident.  I manually changed the normal node which is the manual labor I want to eliminate.

Python with a frame change handler is the least desired at this point.

Comment: Is the object option of the Texture Coordinates node not working?

Comment: It is nor clear what you want. You show a Normal node in the image (which is the same across the whole surface) but you talk about geometric normal. Do you want to rotate this single Normal vector which another object's rotation?

Comment: @sambler  The object option appears to texture both sides of the simple sphere.  That is undesirable in this case.